# WCF waiting for database change

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf

I have following scenario:

- client 1 ----- wcf service ----- client 2.
- Client 1 is php website, and client 2 is wcf client. Database mentioned below is SQL 2008 R2.
- Client 1 sends a request to wcf service (can be considered as a task) which should be processed at client 2 side. According to requirement,
- client 2 side cannot receive incoming requests. Current idea is to save task in database, then client 2 is regularly asking for new tasks.
- When client 2 finishes task, it will inform wcf service, which will update status of the task in database.

Furthermore, our client demands such flow: when client 1 sends a request, it should wait for task to be finished (or timeout expiry). Simple way would be that wcf service stores a task, and then does some database polling in that same request method, checking if status of that task has changed.

Is there any way it can be done without polling database?
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a "message queue".  SQL Server already has one.  You can start with some of the original documentation:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my question. Sorry I cannot understand how message queue can help here. Maybe some SQL trigger could. But it is a question, how to do it: one thread at wcf service receives request, and then should be somehow notified of task completion while connection from client 1 is still open. I am not sure if I was clear enough.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have found sqltabledependency here: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency. It uses service broker and queues under the hood.